# how to change "Read more" button position

Tags: php

Basically what title say.
I'm new to wordpress and I'm working on a website and I need to move the position of the "read more" button to another div inside of the post resume but I can't find which .php file is in charge of that.

Comment: Please provide more details as in which page, which theme are you using, are you using a plugin etc. Please read: [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first understand how WP theme hierarchy works , then only you will be able to find which file you need to define.

Below is the URL to understand how WP theme hierarchy works.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

My trick is not to move the button but create another button.

```
    <style>
/*remove the default button*/
    article p a{
    display: none
    }
    </style>
<!---create a new button in the loop.php file with a link --->
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info">
                    Read more
                </button>
            </a>
```